# BrilliantRetail: Stripe gateway is not working

Tags: brilliantretail

I'm trying to process a payment with Stripe, but am getting an error after the form submits:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function retrieve() on a non-object in /home/redchair/ee/expressionengine/third_party/brilliant_retail/core/gateway/gateway.stripe.php on line 406
```

Any thoughts what the issue may be?

Thanks!

p.s. BrilliantRetail 1.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You possibly use a new Strip API, but BR is not supported it. I get this errors before, so you can try [my patch](https://github.com/MaxLazar/brilliantretail-stripe-fix).